# Instantiating a new object with Constructor parameters using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm trying to refactor some code to use IoC with the Ninject framework. So far I have managed to successfully inject in classes in scenarios where I do not have any constructor parameters to pass. However I am having difficulties when it comes to passing in parameters. This is the third binding in the binding class below.

**Binding Class**

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>();
            Bind<IPlayerDatadao>().To<PlayerDatadao>();
            Bind<IPlayerScores>().To<PlayerScores>();
        }
    }
```

The logger class has a parameterless constructor and works fine when transferred to Ninject.

**Success**

```
    // IoC creation
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    //Log User details
    var logger = kernel.Get<ILogger>();
    logger.LogVisitorDetails();
```

However, my attempt below threw an exception

**Failure**

```
        string priceString = Foo();
        string pointsString = Bar();

        return kernel.Get<IPlayerScores>(new[] { new ConstructorArgument("pointsString", pointsString), new ConstructorArgument("points", priceString) });
```

This is the class with its constructor.

**Class to Inject**

```
public class PlayerScores : IPlayerScores
{
    [Inject]
    public string points { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public string price { get; set; }
    public PlayerScores(string Points, string Price)
    {
        points = Points;
        price = Price;
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure how I should be handling the parameters either in the binding class or at the point of injection

Comment: `PlayerScores` doesn't seem like a component (a class with behavior). It's a data container. Those kinds of objects (DTOs View Models, messages, entities) should not be constructed by your DI Container. Also note that even if `PlayerScopes` is a component (which its name does not imply), it should [not be injected with runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really not sure how I should be handling the parameters either in the binding class or at the point of injection

At binding. You should remove any Ninject dependencies from your model:

```
public class PlayerScores : IPlayerScores
{
    public PlayerScores(string points, string price)
    {
        this.Points = points;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public string Points { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

and then configure the kernel:

```
Bind<IPlayerScores>()
    .To<PlayerScores>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("points", "some points")
    .WithConstructorArgument("price", "some price");
```

or using `ToMethod` which is a bit more refactor friendly as it avoids the magic strings with the parameter names:

```
Bind<IPlayerScores>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => new PlayerScores("some points", "some price"));
```

This being said, if the 2 parameters are so volatile that they need to have a different value on each call, then you probably should not be passing them as constructor parameters but rather as parameters to some instance method that you would invoke on the class at runtime.

Comment: I tried both of those but they end up passing that string literal "some points" into the constructor rather then the dynamic value that I want to pass in.

Comment: Yes, that's expected - the whole point of my answer is that the constructor arguments should be known when configuring your kernel - at bind time. If this is not the case, please see the remark at the end of my answer - the last paragraph.